# Why does this Double value comparison not evaluate as true?

Tags: excel, vba, double

I have the following in cell data/formula:

```
A1: 60
A2: 8000
A3: 4000
A4: =COS(A1*PI()/180)*A2/1000
```

I am trying to run this very simple code snippet in my project:

```
Dim x as Double, y as Double

x = Sheet1.Range("A3")
y = Sheet1.Range("A4")
If (x / 1000) = y Then
    z = z + 0.0001
    Debug.Print z
End If
```

I would expect this comparison to evaluate as true. However, it never does so and thus does not execute my manipulation on z. Both x and y are type `Double`. The Locals window also tells me these values are 4000 and 4, and when I use `Debug.Print` after setting x and y it tells me the same thing.

I know this seems like it should be a really easy problem, but I wouldn't post it here if it were working. What am I missing that is causing this logical failure?

Comment: Use ROUND() or INT() to fix the floating point decimal error: `IF INT(x / 1000) = y Then`

Comment: Agree with @ScottCraner but I can't reproduce your problem with those values.

Comment: Unable to reproduce it for the given value of x and y.

Comment: `However, it never does so and thus does not execute my manipulation on z` How do you know that? Did you step through the code? Try putting a `MsgbBox "Test"` in side the if/endif?

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes, I put a breakpoint on that z line and it never executes. I tried stepping through it line by line too.

Comment: Are you getting `x` and `y` from somewhere (the sheet, another calculation perhaps), or do you explicitly have `x = 4000` and `y = 4`?

Comment: `Debug.Print (x / 1000)` before that and see what do you get. Similarly do it for y as well.

Comment: @BigBen, yes, the values are getting read from two different cells in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Ah well that might be the root cause. What do `Debug.Print x = 4000` and `Debug.Print y = 4` return?

Comment: @manoj0790: No you did not neutralize... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311406/is-it-wrong-to-use-an-upvote-to-balance-out-a-downvote

Comment: @ScottCraner using `Int((x / 1000)) = y` also didn't work. Neither did CInt

Comment: @BigBen is right. Your worksheet cell values have decimals. Can you debug.print x and y before the `If`?

Comment: Check your locale variables window please just before you think x and y have these values

Comment: @SiddharthRout @JvdV normally those values would have decimals, but in this case 4000 is specified by me and 4 was derived from `8*sin(30)` which evaluates neatly to 4 exactly.

Comment: `8*sin(30)` evaluates to exactly 4? You sure? I'm not great at math but it evaluates to -0,98803 for me. Could you use `Val(Range.Text)` to get your 4 into x and see if that works?

Comment: @SandPiper is that a typo? `8*sin(30)` does not equal 4

Comment: Ok - so sin(30)=0.5 in degrees.... but `Sin` uses radians.

Comment: @BigBen Yes, it evaluates using radians. I typed the comment in degrees because sin(30 degrees) is more recognizable as one half than sin(.52359 radians). The cell is actually a much longer formula that under the current conditions simplifies down to that. I didn't mean to cause confusion with that. The resulting value is a decimal number though. The value for x is specified by the user, but is normally an integer. It doesn't have to be though.

Comment: Ok gotcha - sorry this has been confusing. I would then use `Int` on `y` as well. Edited the "answer" :)

Comment: Piper, did you try debuging as suggested **many** times above? What do you get when you do  `Debug.Print X` and `Debug.Print Y` before the `IF`

Comment: In my experience, doing comparisons on calculated doubles is error prone as suggested by Scott Craner.  The simple solution is to always `Round` before comparing.

Comment: @BrianMStafford, maybe worth pointing out that `Round` uses bankers' rounding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @bigben I'll try to identify more specifics later. I'm a little dismayed by all the hate here though. I agree it looks like it should have a simple answer, but I'm not an idiot. I wouldn't have posted if it was behaving as expected. I feel like I got written off in a hurry here.

Comment: I don't doubt that. I think part of the reaction is that this felt like a wild-goose chase. But most likely it's floating-point error. We really do need a reproducible example. And without your formula that results in `y`, we can't reproduce the behavior. I think we need the *actual* formula, not a simplification of it.

Comment: @siddharthroutt yes, I tried debug.print and it just output 4 and 4000 each time. Nothing like 4.00000000001 or something that would make sense on why this logic was failing.

Comment: @SandPiper Just because the watch window, locals window, debug.print, or immediate window doesn't show the imprecision doesn't mean it's not there.  The IDE just isn't showing it, but it is there in many cases.  As Scott Craner said in the first comment on this post, you somehow need to address the imprecision of doubles.  The link provided by @Storax gives a lot of good background information and some solutions.  In summary, either use the `epsilon` technique or simply round the numbers before you compare.  I've done it both ways, but I usually find rounding to be sufficient.

Comment: @SandPiper As a side note, I also think it too bad the question was closed.  Reproducible example?  Try `? .1 + .2` and `? .1 + .2 = 0.3` in the immediate window.

Comment: @BigBen I edited the post to include the formula that one of the variables draws from. If I could get some help reopening the post I would appreciate it.

Comment: Voted to reopen.

Comment: @SiddharthRout post edited. Are you willing to provide a reopen vote?

Comment: Voted to reopen

Comment: Instead of `Double`, declare it as `Currency`

Comment: https://bettersolutions.com/vba/numbers/currency-data-type.htm. You can also search more in Google for `double vs currency vba`

Comment: Just to prove the point , add `Debug.Print (x / 1000) - y` to the code, before the `If`.  I get `-8.88178419700125E-16`